# Can I use iptables, Shorewall and ipset on the same time?

Tags: iptables, firewall, router, shorewall

I'm using iptables for years, because it is a straightforward solution without any magic. But now I'm building a router for myself, I found there are many useful features provided by Shorewall.

Is it possible to use iptables and Shorewall on the same time? I know Shorewall is just a frontend of iptables. But I don't know whether cause a conflict.

Also, I need to block tons of addresses, so ipset is the perfect solution. Is it safe to use all these three firewalls?

Answer (score 1):

As you said :

> Shorewall is just a frontend of iptables

So, in your opinion, what could be a very good reason to use both ?

Furthermore, `ipsets` can be used with pure `iptables`, but `Shorewall` also supports `ipsets` : http://www.shorewall.net/ipsets.html

So, i would say : use `iptables` **OR** `Shorewall` (as front-end).

Using both makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Shorewall and ipsets are totally complementary, shorewall is like is said above a front-end tool to manage iptables correctly. Ipsets is a tool to whitelist/blacklist big sets of ips much more efficiently, so they are can work together and mostly all sysadmin, that I know, recommend it.

The main consideration to be taken care of, is that in order to get shorewall working with ipsets, your [kernel needs to support ipset match](http://shorewall.net/manpages/shorewall-blacklist.html) (IPSET_MATCH). To check if your server has support for it, run:

```
$ shorewall show -f capabilities | grep IPSET_MATCH
```

you should see:

```
IPSET_MATCH=Yes
```

In order to being able to use shorewall with ipset. This support depends totally on your kernel and your OS.

My experience was that, in order to make it working, I need to update iptables and ipset package to the last version:

```
iptables v1.6.0
ipset v6.27, protocol version: 6
```

because in that version the support to ipset match is added by the package. You can read the [changelog](http://ipset.netfilter.org/changelog.html) of ipset. But it is possible that your kernel already support it. As this package version are not in Jessie repository (at this moment at least), I needed to install them from testing repository, which is not the most recommendable approach, but it worked perfectly.